# gstreamer flvmux and rtmp error

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, flv

I trying to stream rtmp from rasberrypi, the omx hardware encoder worked really nice, by the way, so I'm running:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! «video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1» !\
 omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable !\
 video/x-h264,profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! \
flvmux name=mux alsasrc device=plughw:1 ! audioresample ! \
audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=1 ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=32000 ! queue ! mux. mux. !\
 rtmpsink location='rtmp://my_rtmp_for_ustream.tv_url'
```

And there is an error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2812): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSrc:alsasrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 535913298 ns.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
libv4l2: warning v4l2 mmap buffers still mapped on close()
Freeing pipeline ...
```

First of all i thought that there is some alsa problems or such, but then I tried to write simple mpegts and it worked:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! «video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1» ! \
omxh264enc target-bitrate=1000000 control-rate=variable !\
 video/x-h264,profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! \
 mpegtsmux name=mux alsasrc device=plughw:1 ! audioresample !\
 audio/x-raw,rate=48000,channels=1 ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=32000 ! \
queue ! mux. mux. ! filesink location=1.ts
```

But i can't just change "filesink location=1.ts" to rtmpsink location='rtmp://my_rtmp_for_ustream.tv_url' because i'll get an error:

WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link mux to rtmpsink0

So, what can I do to get it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real problem was that rtmpsync need raw aac, so I added aacparse and it worked out, something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! \
   "video/x-raw, framerate=25/1, width=320, height=240" ! \
   omxh264enc target-bitrate=300000 control-rate=variable ! \
   h264parse ! queue ! flvmux name=muxer alsasrc device=hw:1 ! \
   audioresample ! "audio/x-raw,rate=48000" ! queue ! \
   voaacenc bitrate=32000 ! aacparse ! queue ! muxer. muxer. ! \
   rtmpsink location="$RTMP_URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

rtmpsink requires data in "video/x-flv" format. Your first pipeline clearly showing negotiation error. Can you get me caps negotiation dump of your pipeline by adding -v in command line.