# Why there is no voice when I use the voaacenc and faad of gstreamer to encoder and decoder

Tags: ubuntu, audio, gstreamer

The command line is as following :

send：

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! 'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,width=16,channels=1' ! voaacenc ! rtpmp4apay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5002
```

receive ：

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5002 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio" ! rtpmp4adepay ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink
```

when I playing them on the ubuntu, they all can run, but I cannot hear anything on the receive, when I use `gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc ! voaacenc ! faad ! autoaudiosink`, there is some voice I can hear, why and how can I solve it?

Comment: You may try adding aacparse to sending pipe as it is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034375/gstreamer-flvmux-and-rtmp-error) but I cannot test this because I do not have voaacenc and faad installed..